# Node.js method invocation remotely

Tags: web-services, http, node.js, websocket, rpc

I am taking my first steps with Node.js and I was wondering whether there is some way to invoke a JS method define server-side (using Node.js) but from the client side. e.g.

```
function read_file_server_side(id){
  // Do stuff on the server side.
}
```

and then, from the client side we need to be able to invoke the method. Of course, I understand that it is possible to wrap the server-side method using REST principles; i.e. expose it to the client as a web service and have the clients using HTTP requests. But it comes handy if one could make use of the function directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of socket.io, I'd rather point you to [Now.js](http://nowjs.com). It does exactly what you want : share functions server side on the client side.

Comment: Be patient! There's anyway a time restriction between the time you post a question and when you're able to accept it. But, of course, here's the green tick for you!

Comment: Now.js is built on top Socket.io which it requires as a dependency. Do not see how this is better.

Comment: Because this is just the abstraction needed: no more, no less.

Comment: Yes abstraction at the cost of another dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Well the thing about node is there is modules for everything.‌ For everything there is an "initial commit" and most probably in github. For this case, it's part of every app to make a request to server from client side or in other words to make a RPC call. The basic transport method in this case is ajax. And on some modern browsers, we have websockets. For ajax, this is the simplest method that you can make something you want:

On client side:

```
var request.ajax('/ajax/setLolz', {data : 'nice', type : 'post'})

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#lolz").html( msg );
});
```

on server side:

```
var url  = reruire('url')
var http = require('http');
var lolz = 'wow';
var methods = {
  '/ajax/setLolz' : function (action, body, res) {
    res.end(lolz);
    lolz = body;
    someOtherFunction();
  }
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var body = '';
  var action = url.parse(req.url);

  req.on('body', function(text) {
    body += text;
  }

  req.on('end', function() {
    methods[action.path](action, body, res);
  }

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

This was simple ajax. You make it a little better by using [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/):

```
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect()
  .use(connect.bodyParser())
  .use(function(req, res){
    var action = url.parse(req.url);
    methods[action.path](action, body, res);
  })
 .listen(1337);
```

Or more simpler with [express](http://expressjs.com/):

```
var app = require('express');
var app = express.createServer()
  .use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/ajax/setLolz', function(req, res){
  res.end(lolz);
  lolz = req.body;
  someOtherFunction();
});

app.listen(1337);
```

And yeah, there lots of [modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules) that can help you.

As of websockets, the most fastest  websocket server that I know is [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws). Though some browsers may not support it.

On client side:

```
websocket = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/ws');
websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
  websocket.send(JSON.stringify({method : 'setLolz', msg : 'yes '};
};
websocket.onmessag = function(evt) {
  $("#lolz").html( evt.data );
}
```

On server:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/ws');
var methods = {
  'setLolz' : function (msg, ws) {
    ws.send(lolz);
    lolz = msg;
    someOtherFunction();
  }
}

ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  methods[data.method](data.msg);
});
```

Then there's the [socket.io](http://socket.io/), that makes things much easier. It's cross browser and works everywhere. Built on ajax and websockets and some other methods. You patch everything to events. You can even use it beside an http server listening on the same port.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(1337);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('setLolz', function(data) {
    socket.emit('lolz', lolz);
    lolz = data;
  });
  socket.on('setLolz', someOtherFunction);// Yes, you can listen to an event with two functions
});
```

But still it's not simple enough, so now I introduce you to [nowjs](http://nowjs.com/).

On browser:

```
now.setLolz(function(data){
  $("#lolz").html( data );
});
```

On server side:

```
var nowjs = require("now");
var app = nowjs.initialize(httpServer);

app.now.setLolz = function(cb){
  cb(lolz);
  lolz = data;
  someOtherFunction();
}
```

I don't wanna go in deeper, but I hope you got the gist. There are also other modules(dnode, hook.io, flatiron, railwayjs, racer, locomotivejs, ...) that can help you. And yes, you can always make your own.

Happy coding... :D

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)

You basically can call a method on the server side easy and fast.

Server:

```
socket.on('doAwesomeStuff', function (data) {
   startDoingAwesomeStuff();
}

function startDoingAwesomeStuff() {
   // this would be the remotely invoked method.
   ...
}
```

Client:

```
socket.emit('doAwesomeStuff', { my: 'data' });
```

Comment: I didn't see how one can invoke a method that lies on the server from the client side. Is it possible? Can you provide an example (even pseudo code)?